Docker closes bash on error/failed command
I have a docker file that ends with CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]. I am able to start it using docker compose <service>  up -d and attach to a terminal session using docker compose <service> bash.
But the bash session closes if there are any errors/failed commands (eg. misspelled commands), at which point I have to attach again and pick up where I left off. Is there a way to keep bash alive even when a command fails? I tried using docker run -it .... but that had the same issue

What are you trying to do with this container; why is running sleep infinity useful?  Can you set the image's CMD to more directly do the thing you need the container to do, without worrying about "keeping the container alive"?  Especially making CMD be a script that you can lint and test seems like it'd help the problem of making mistakes entering manual commands.

You can use set +e bash option to continue next commands even if there are some errors
So, for example, you can use the command below to start new bash session:
docker-compose <service> exec -it <service> bash -c "set +e; exec bash"


This worked for me, but not with the -c syntax. I ended up adding set +e to the .bashrc in the docker image. Thank you!
